# sys.stdout.flush() won't work

Tags: python, buffer, flush, sys

```
import sys
from graphics import *

win = GraphWin("test", 500, 500)
while True:
    pt = win.getMouse()
    print(pt.getX(), pt.getY())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

I'm trying to get the code to return both the X and Y coordinates to the screen at the same time, but what I get after clicking in the window a few times is something that look like:

123 200

443 67

104

After I close the window the program spits out the last "84" and then reads:

123 200

443 67

104 84

But I want it to do that while i'm still in the window clicking on new points.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does it work if you run python with the `-u` argument?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm not familiar with '-u', I am really quite new to python.

Comment: Usually people get familar with things just by trying them. Run `python -u yourscript.py`!

Comment: @KlausD. I am so new to python that I do not know what you mean when you say that. Do i type that in at the beginning of the code?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#invoking-the-interpreter The other parts might be helpful as well.

Comment: @KlausD. my friend tried it on his computer also using windows and his worked...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it> I was running in a old version of wing IDE 5.0.9 to be exact, so I updated to 6.0.1 and it worked.

Note: My friend was using version 5.1.0 and it worked fine on his too.